# How do you specify a:link style in a div class implementation?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

I have an anchor tag in a ...

In my HTML, within the  tag, I have

```
.foo {
     white-space:nowrap;
     text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
     color: #000;
     font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, arial;
     font-size: 12px;
}
```

How do I make it so that I can specify `a:link {COLOR: #ffff;}` in this class?

Answer (score 7):

If your structure is

```
<div class="foo"><a href="...">...</a></div>
```

You can style unvisited links thus:

```
.foo a:link {color: #fff;}
```

Note: use either 3 or 6 `f`s, not 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
<p class="CLASSE"><a href="/Profile">Profile</a></p>

.CLASSE a, .CLASSE a:hover{
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which element within a certain CSS class or ID by putting the element name (by itself) after the class or ID name. Try this:

```
.foo a {color: #ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want

.foo a:link {COLOR: #ffffff;}